# Is it okay to perform many queries with mysql or should I look to optimize?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm relatively new to programming and have been working in a project group to create our first proper website. We have products and a page where we want to display multiple of those products depending on which category is selected.

```
$productlist = new ProductList($DB_con, htmlspecialchars($_POST['categoryID'])); 
$productids = $productlist->getids();
$product = new Product($DB_con);
foreach ($productids as $id) {
    $product->read($id);
    echo $product->productname
}
```

Now this is just a basic example of what I'm talking about but essentially the `foreach` loop would iterate over `read($id)` numerous times meaning it will essentially perform a query for each product. Now my question is if this is really the acceptable way to go about it or whether I should look to perform one query and somehow grab the data out of that query instead(or any other alternative).

Comment: It's generally far more efficient to execute a single query (possibly using a JOIN)... each round trip to the database and back is a big overhead

Comment: It's better to run 1 query and pull all of the products from a certain category. If your table structure is set up correctly this isn't difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a job for a SQL `WHERE IN`. If you have an array of Ids you can simply run:

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, n...)`

You can generate the numbers with:

```
$ids = implode(", ", $productids);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN ({$ids})";
```

Comment: That's quite useful, I'll keep it in mind! I ended up just rewriting the bit to a single query instead though.